# Prove that the cosine of the angle between $CE$ and $CA$ is $\frac{3\sqrt7}{8}$

Tags: geometry

In the isosceles triangle $ABC,AB=BC=8,$ and $CA=12$,a point $E$ divides $AB$ internally in the ratio $1:3$,then prove that the cosine of the angle between $CE$ and $CA$ is $\frac{3\sqrt7}{8}$.

---

My Attempt:Let $\frac{AE}{EB}=\frac{1}{3}$.Let $\angle ACE=\phi$ and $\angle BAC=\angle ACB=\theta$ and as the point E divides $AB$ in the ratio $1:3$,so $\theta=4\phi$.
Then i calculated $\cos\theta$ using cosine law and it comes out $\frac{3}{4}$
$\cos\theta=\cos4\phi=\frac{3}{4}$
$2\cos^22\phi-1=\frac{3}{4}$
$\cos2\phi=\sqrt{\frac{7}{8}}$
$2\cos^2\phi-1=\sqrt{\frac{7}{8}}$
And i am not getting the desired answer.Where have i gone wrong?Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Why do you put $\theta=4\phi$?

Comment: Because $CE$ divides $AB$ in the ratio of $1:3$,so it also divides the angle ACB in the same ratio.

Comment: That is not true.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia your statement will imply that every median is also an angle bisector, which is not true.

Comment: use the theorem of cosine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Stewart's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart's_theorem) we have:

$$ 12^2\cdot 6 + 8^2\cdot 2 = 8\cdot(CE^2+2\cdot 6) $$
hence $CE=4\sqrt{7}$. The cosine theorem then gives:
$$ \cos\widehat{ACE} = \frac{AC^2+CE^2-AE^2}{2\cdot AC\cdot CE} = \frac{12^2+112-4}{96\sqrt{7} } = \color{red}{\frac{3\sqrt{7}}{8}}$$
as wanted.